# Match type reduction fails with opaque type

Tags: scala, opaque-types, match-types

[Scastie available here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XLsUj8crQOK5IeeOvin4Tg)

I am having issues using match types with opaque types as scrutinees. In the following snippet the type of `b` is simply not reduced (`b: Match[T1[Char]]` instead of `b: String`).

**Note:** everything works fine as soon as `T1` is not opaque anymore

```
object Foo:
    type Match[A] = A match
        case Int => String
        case T1[a] => String

    opaque type T1[A] = Double
    // type T1[A] = Double


import Foo.*

val a: Match[Int] = "" 
val b: Match[T1[Char]] = ""       //doesn't compile
```

Is this a known issue or am I missing something ?

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/17580